# vscode input redirection not work properly

Tags: python, redirect, visual-studio-code, input

I am using vscode.

I want to get input from input.txt when running python in vscode.

So I set launch.json like below. (added "args")

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "args": [
                "<",
                "input.txt"
            ],
            "name": "Python: Curre545435nt File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

(refer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target)

Now when I run python, vscode sends a command like below.

```sh
c:; cd 'c:\Users\user\Desktop\ct'; & 
'C:\Users\user\miniconda3\python.exe' 
 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' 
  '13094 ' '--' 'c:\Users\user\Desktop\workingfolder\.vscode\launch.json' 
   '<' 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\workingfolder\input.txt'
```

The problem here is the ' on both sides of the <. (**'**<**'**)

As a result of testing directly in the terminal, it was confirmed that it should be modified as shown below to run properly.

`'python.exe' '<' 'input.txt' (not correct)`

`'python.exe' < 'input.txt' (correct)`

What settings do I need to set in vscode to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to work in the PowerShell for now, you can try switch to the `cmd`.

If you don't know how to switch the terminal type, you can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles).

Comment: perfect!! thanks a lot :)